# invalid number specified with option "/HEAP:1[,10]"

Tags: windows, visual-c++, linker, heap-memory

My Malloc is failing in my project.
Malloc runs several times via a one of the functions but fails due to lack of memory.

I am trying to increase the heap size in my VC++ but it gives me the error as above in the subject.

Can someone please tell me what is wrong in this ?

Windows server 2003 R2 Enterprise edition
And i am using VC++ 98 edition.

I tried some search but could not get anything conclusive on how to use /HEAP OPTION.
should the numbers be in MB ?

```
message_t* Allocate_momory(MsgType_t msgType, UInt16 dataLength)
{
    // TO DO: Allocate memenory and return the pointer
    message_t* mes_t;
    mes_t = (message_t*) malloc(sizeof (message_t));
    mes_t->msgType = msgType;
    mes_t->dataLength = 0;
    mes_t->clientID = 0;
    mes_t->usageCount = 0;
    mes_t->dataBuf = malloc(sizeof (dataLength));
    return mes_t;
}
```

Yes it worked... But it unfortunatly did not solve my problem with malloc :( !!
This is a huge project with too many files.
I can't post the code but can someone guide me how should i try to debug a problem where malloc is failing ?

Comment: I am trying :- but i can't get rid of the error.invalid number specified with option "/HEAP:11.0"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[/HEAP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90ybzkh.aspx) sets the heap size in *bytes*. Also the square brackets in the [documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f90ybzkh.aspx) denote an optional parameter - you don't actually type these in. So it would be e.g.

```
/HEAP:1073741824
```

for a 1 GB heap, or

```
/HEAP:1073741824,16777216
```

if you really do want to specify the "commit" parameter in addition to the heap size (you probably don't).

Unfortunately I don't think this will solve your *real* problem, which is that you are running out of memory. You may have [memory leaks](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Memory_leak), which you can track down with a tool such as [valgrind](http://valgrind.org). If that's not the case then you have a bad design, which will be a lot harder to fix than memory leaks.

Comment: Yes it worked... But it unfortunatly did not solve my problem with malloc :( !!
This is a huge project with too many files.
I can't post the code but can someone guide me how should i try to debug a problem where malloc is failing ?

Comment: +1, although you could have offered some advice as well. @user1566968: Sure. Free some memory before allocating more. If you're having trouble with `malloc` failing, you're trying to keep too much in memory at the same time. Maybe it's time to look at some kind of database or other on-disk storage?